# DOJO architecture flow

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Can someone suggest how a DOJO scripts gets executed , in terms of **architectural diagrams or flow steps diagram**.

How DOM nodes are created and how the data gets populated or rendered? I am not clear about the concept how a DOM tree is created and how the widgets get populated with data. What is the concept of Model?

Can someone explain just in terms of some simple flow diagram, the picture is not very clear from the documentations provided in the sitepan or dojotoolkit site.

Comment: Dojo is a really broad framework. Even when you talk about models, widgets and modules, there are several ways to load them, either asynchronously (XHR) or directly. I don't think it's possible to give you a global overview of everything.

Comment: can you explain me else how the date flows and a DOM tree is created giving a simple example. I want to understand how DOM tree is created and and how widgets interact with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for dojos a javascript based Programming language, you can have a look here:

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

There are some nice Models that explain, how the DOM is working. Sadly it's only good explained in german, but i think the mainessence would be clear to understand.

This second one explaines it also very good: http://ils.indiana.edu/faculty/hrosenba/www/Demo/javascript2/DOM.html

and here's a third one from the W3Schools.com : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Regards, Miriam

Comment: really nice links..I was searching for this

Comment: I think i need to learn German :) as the first link looks substantial